# Printing multliple divs on separate pages

Tags: html, css

i'm working with a HTML round-robin group table and i'd like it to print every table on another page. For that i've followed some guidelines found from this page. At first i changed my float's into inline-blocks, then i tried to use print.css but it did not come to the result i wanted.

Currently it displays both tables however if I try to print it it will display only one page.

Image 1:
[image: page]
Image 2:
[image: print]

As seen from pictures, page displays two tables although print wants to print only one and there is no second page.

CSS:

```
@media print {
@page {size: landscape}
.myDivToPrint {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.breaker{
    /*page-break-after:always;*/
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container myDivToPrint">
    <div id="4table0" class="breaker">
    <table style="display: inline-block">
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="display: inline-block;margin-left: -5px">
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>

    </table> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>I VOOR</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px">1-4</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px">2-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>II VOOR</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px">2-4</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px">1-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>III VOOR</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px">3-4</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px">1-2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    </div>

    <div id="5table0" style="padding-bottom: 5px" class="breaker">
    <table style="display: inline-block">
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableName">
            <td class='namefield'>Name 5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="display: inline-block; margin-left: -5px">
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="groupTableRows">
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td class="groupTableRowsBACK">&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

PS: It seems like class breaker in CSS does not change the print at all..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `page-break-after` attribute:

```
@media print {
    div{
        page-break-after:always;
    }
}
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently leaving out position: fixed from CSS fixed this case.